# How to handle JS destructing assignment with one of the array element is null?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the array destructing assignment to get the results from Promise.all().  Here is my code:

```
const[_, resFunc2] = await Promise.all([
      func1(),
      func2(),
    ]);
```

func1 doesn't return any value, and func2 returns a value which will be assigned to resFunc2.
I want to ask what's the best practice for handling the result of func1 since func1 doesn't return any value?
Thanks a lot~

Comment: Do you mean that `func1` returns a promise that resolve in `null`?

Comment: Have you tried using `Array#filter` to remove `undefined` values? `.filter(x => x !== undefined)`

Comment: Reverse the order of the promises and then deconstruct to just one array value. Ignoring the second value as it will be discarded.

Comment: @cgTag, this is a good solution

Comment: @Federkun, yes.

Comment: What's the problem with assigning `null`?

Comment: You can use default values `const [a = 0, b] = [null, 1]`. Does it always return null? You can discard it `const [, b] = [null, 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered the [simplest possibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)?

```
const resFunc2 = (await Promise.all([
      func1(),
      func2(),
    ]))[1];
```

If you are insistent on destructuring (I have to admit, it's super-cool), you could do this.

```
const [resFunc2] = await Promise.all([
      func2(),
      func1(),
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of possibilities, depending on what you need to do with the result.

You can use default values if you need a specific value.

```
const [_ = 0, resFunc2] = await Promise.all([
      func1(),
      func2(),
]);
```

You can omit it if you don't need it at all

```
const [, resFunc2] = await Promise.all([
      func1(),
      func2(),
]);
```

<sub>*Disclaimer: I didn't test any of these*</sub>

Comment: I really like your second solution.  I didn't know that was even allowed.  Almost as good as [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56177609/238884) :-).  I didn't know about the first possibility either, but I don't think it fits the need.  The third one can go wrong too many ways.

Comment: Thank you :) - I agree with you on all points! - I like the second one because it expresses its intent quite readable. - number three doesn't make much sense, i'll better remove it, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I came up with a (fourth?  fifth?) solution!  Still enamored of the empty-comma syntax though.